# Navigation bar in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, appbar

How can i implement a windows 8 navigation bar like the one in weather app or finance app.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add top app bar, like this:

```
<Page.TopAppBar>
    <AppBar>
        <!--App Bar Contents here -->
    </AppBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

and than add navigation buttons inside of app bar.